# Windows equivalent of $export

Tags: windows

I am trying to follow some instructions for creating a directory using the command line. The instructions are:

```
$ export PROJ_HOME=$HOME/proj/111
$ export PROJECT_BASEDIR=PROJ_HOME/exercises/ex1
$ mkdir -p $PROJ_HOME
```

Are these windows commands? Are there windows equivalents?

Comment: No, these are *nix commands.  The Windows equivalent for mkdir is mkdir.

Comment: [set varname=value](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/environment_variables.html)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

To translate your *nix style command script to windows/command batch style it would go like this:

```
SET PROJ_HOME=%USERPROFILE%/proj/111
SET PROJECT_BASEDIR=%PROJ_HOME%/exercises/ex1
mkdir "%PROJ_HOME%"
```

mkdir on windows doens't have a -p parameter : from the MKDIR /? help:

> MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.

which basically is what mkdir -p (or --parents for purists) on *nix does, as [taken from the man guide](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows10, I needed to do it manually.

Comment: Just verified on Windows10 and works for me @Shadowbob but maybe you have a space in one of the directory names?

Comment: will these environment variables be permanent using 'SET' in windows? I know that with export they will be temporary unless you add them to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: @user137717 they are temporary. Use the `setx` command if you want to change/add those variable to the system or user settings and persist them.

Answer (score 6):

There is not an equivalent statement for export in Windows Command Prompt.
In Windows the environment is copied so when you exit from the session (from a called command prompt or from an executable that set a variable) the variable in Windows get lost. You can set it in user registry or in machine registry via setx but you won't see it if you not start a new command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `export` if you have git-bash installed.

Comment: Its not working on windows.

Comment: @AbhishekSachan are you using git bash? I crossed check it even now and its working for me.

Comment: Somehow it's not working in windows 10. Might be some installation issue, thanks for confirming.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that this is an option. That's way easier than using the WSL.

Comment: it worked thanks... great help.... For people, its not working.. please try giving full path of the configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10+, it is preserved for an user forever, run as admin for global var

```
setx myvariable myvariablevalue
```