# Change path of the package directory in Julia (on Windows)

Tags: windows, julia

How can I change the path of the package directory in Julia? I not found answer in documentation from section [Package Manager Functions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/pkg/?highlight=pkg.dir#Base.Pkg.dir). 
I use Julia v0.4.6 on Windows.

Comment: @GnimucK., thanks, but the proposed solution did not fit. Windows shell does not know of the export command.

Comment: on windows, you can [manually add a new environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)  `JULIA_PKGDIR`

Comment: @GnimucK.,  yes, after setting this variable, julia still "saw" the old path. Then I set ENV["JULIA_PKGDIR"] in julia shell and began to perform the rest of the commands from your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

How about this command from the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/modules/):

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "C:\Path\To\My\Module\")
```

Which can be run from within Julia, or, as the docs say:

> Putting this statement in the file ~/.juliarc.jl will extend LOAD_PATH on every Julia startup. Alternatively, the module load path can be extended by defining the environment variable JULIA_LOAD_PATH.

**Option 2**

The SET command in windows should be equivalent to export in unix/linux based systems: [Windows equivalent of $export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701783/windows-equivalent-of-export).  E.g.

```
SET JULIA_PKGDIR=C:\your\directory
```

From here, this should enable one to follow the answer from @Gnimuc: [Change Package directory in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398629/change-package-directory-in-julia)

Comment: thanks for the response, but unfortunately cannot test option 1 - found another solution(option 2).

Comment: `push!(LOAD_PATH, "C:\Path\To\My\Module\")` only works for the current session. What do I need to do to make this persist after restarting Julia?