# Unable to print environmental variable in python which is set manually by the user to use that variable in later part of code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, path, environment-variables

I added a environmental variable manually as setx NEWVAR SOMETHING, 
so that my tool later uses the NEWVAR variable in the script but I am unable to access it, please help. Also below is the code. And for your information I am able to access the predefined system variables

```
try:  
   kiran=os.environ["NEWVAR"]
   print kiran
except KeyError: 
   print "Please set the environment variable NEWVAR"
   sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your environment variable is persistent following a restart of your shell otherwise your new environment variable will not be accessible later on

```
ekavala@elx75030xhv:/var/tmp$ export NEWVAR='alan'
ekavala@elx75030xhv:/var/tmp$ python test.py 
alan
*closes shell and reopens*
ekavala@elx75030xhv:/var/tmp$ python test.py 
Please set the environment variable NEWVAR
```

Update your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` with the variable instead of just doing a `setx` or `export`

Note: If you update `/etc/environment` you will need to reboot your computer to have the environment variables set in your shell

Comment: As i am using windows system can u please tell me where can i set environmental variable (path)permanently . i added in advance system settings even then i  am facing issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setx to set those environment variables; try using EXPORT.  The following example worked for me.

```
export MYCUSTOMVAR="testing123"
python testing.py
```

Note: If you are on Windows you can set the env variable with SET.

```
SET MYCUSTOMVAR=testing123
```

testing.py

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("MYCUSTOMVAR: {0}".format(os.environ['MYCUSTOMVAR']))
```

output

```
MYCUSTOMVAR: testing123
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply kyle i manually added environmental variable in advanced system settings is that fine? as export is not working on my system even after adding manually also i am unable to access it

Comment: It sounds like you are on Windows.  If you are you need to use the SET command as EXPORT doesn't exist on Windows.  See this previous question related to the SET command on Windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701783/windows-equivalent-of-export)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set environment variable through script:

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "somepath"
```

If you set it using command prompt it will be available only for that shell. If you set it in advanced system settings it will available every where but not when you open a new shell inside python script.

Comment: `setx` sets the environment variable permanently. [SS64 Reference](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)