# Export equivalent for windows?

Tags: django, powershell, terminal, environment-variables, django-deployment

I am following a tutorial on building a simple website using django. I am at the stage of preparing my website for deployment. However, when I try to enter

```
export READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
```

into the terminal, I get the error message:

```
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was  
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundE  
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am a windows user, and the tutorial person is a mac user. I don't know why I am getting this error, and I hope you guys could help me export this code. Here are some codes in my settings file for your reference:

```
READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)
if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    environ.Env.read_env()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows equivalent of $export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701783/windows-equivalent-of-export)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, I also looked at that page before uploading this article, and I didn't get any replacement code for "export READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True".

Comment: @JohnSong `SET READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't think it worked if I use SET instead of export.

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux is the bomb. Using the Windows DOS environment for programming is an exercise in frustration.

Comment: So... are you saying that if I use the WSL2, I can just use the export command(as well as other commands available for linux) in the windows terminal?

Answer (score 1):

On windows you should run:

```
setx export READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
```